# Misleading message

Tags: c, gcc

I accidentally wrote `foo ((struct Node* ) head);` instead of `foo ((Node* ) head);`

And I got a message from compiler

*`expected 'struct Node *' but argument is of type 'struct Node *'`*

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct NODE
{ 
  char data; 
  struct NODE *next;
} Node;

void foo (Node *head){}

void bar (void *head)
{
 // note: 
  foo ((struct Node* ) head); 
}

int main(){

return 0;
}
```

This is misleading, shouldn't it be either `Node *` or `struct NODE *` in the first case ?

What does this message mean ? Can anybody clarify it ?

I'm able to reproduce it [here](http://ideone.com/jDUITR) too after intentionally putting an error.

<sup>*Compiler :gcc (GCC) 4.8.1*</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bug in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56980).  You're right that the 'expected' should be either `struct NODE *` or `Node *`.  For what it's worth, clang gives a better message:

```
example.c:13:8: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'struct Node *' to
      parameter of type 'Node *' (aka 'struct NODE *')
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  foo ((struct Node* ) head); 
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
example.c:8:17: note: passing argument to parameter 'head' here
void foo (Node *head){}
                ^
1 warning generated.
```